# add_index in schema for an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am following an open source app as a guide for my app. A little background, I am trying to nest a form in active admin. I am assuming that this is part of their nested form.

OpenSource Schema

```
create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
 t.integer  "addressable_id"
 t.string   "addressable_type"
 t.string   "street"
 t.string   "city"
 t.string   "state",            :limit => 2
 t.integer  "zip"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "addresses", ["addressable_type", "addressable_id"], :name =>  "index_addresses_on_addressable_type_and_addressable_id"
```

My schema is exactly the same except the add_index at the bottom. How are they getting that and maybe if you have time, why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think the migration would have any effect on a form that is being displayed on the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Addresses is polymorphic table, that's why you have addressable_id and addressable_type columns. So EVERY TIME you look for an object address, you have to search in both columns. In order to optimize seek times in the databse, you create an index including those columns.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin is adding an index to the database table in order to improve performance in the database. An index is not an additional row in the table, but a separate construct that allows the database engine to look things up more quickly. A great introductory article can be found here:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/08/30/explaining-indexes-with-a-library-metaphor/

Rails migrations uses the add_index syntax in order to create that index for this database table.